# 'names' string disappears after qsort with 'Symbol' struct

Tags: c, struct, elf, qsort, sortcomparefunction

So I get the ELF function symbols from a file, put them into a new Symbol struct, and sort an array of Symbols alphabetically by name. I use strdup to allocate memory for my string

before qsort:

```
00000000 00000015 t crash_here
00000015 00000014 t winky
00000036 0000002e t dinky
00000029 0000000d T pinky
00000064 00000014 T binky
00000078 00000017 T main
```

after qsort:

```
00000064 00000014 T 
00000000 00000015 t 
00000036 0000002e t 
00000078 00000017 T 
00000029 0000000d T 
00000015 00000014 t
```

What could have gone wrong?!
Here is more code for context:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(!fp) error(1, 0, "'%s': no such file", argv[1]); //check for valid file
size_t nelems = 0; 
Symbol *symbs = (Symbol *)getFunctionSymbols(fp, &nelems);
printAllSymbols(symbs, nelems);
qsort(symbs , nelems, sizeof(Symbol)* sizeof(Symbol), compareSymbAlph);
printAllSymbols(symbs, nelems);

int compareSymbAlph(const void *a, const void *b){
 Symbol *first = (Symbol *)a;
 Symbol *second = (Symbol *)b; 
 return strcmp(first->name, second->name);
}
```

**EDIT**

The qsort function is working and sorting them alphabetically, but somehow the 'names' are being lost in the process.

```
void printSymbol(Symbol *s){
    printf("%08x %08x %c %s\n", s->addr, s->size, s->binding, s->name);
}

void printAllSymbols(Symbol *symbArray, size_t nelems){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nelems; i++){
        Symbol *curr = symbArray + i* sizeof(Symbol); 
        printSymbol(curr); 
    }
}

typedef struct {
    char          *name;            // name of symbol 
    uintptr_t      addr;            // symbol address
    unsigned int   size;            // symbol size in bytes
    unsigned char  binding;         // binding- T for extern or t for static
} Symbol;
```

I know the squaring is odd, but it's working with that! It's hard because it's a big project and I want to include context but not be overwhelming.

Comment: i think you need to post more complete code for anyone to help you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Is is the sort function that's not working, or is the `printAllSymbols` method not working correctly?  Also, you didn't include that, you should add it to your post.

Comment: The third argument to qsort is the size of each element, so I reckon should simply be sizeof(Symbol);  Why are you squaring it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the call of qsort

```
qsort(symbs , nelems, sizeof(Symbol)* sizeof(Symbol), compareSymbAlph);
```

the follwoing way

```
qsort(symbs , nelems, sizeof(Symbol), compareSymbAlph);
```

Function printAllSymbols is also wrong

```
void printAllSymbols(Symbol *symbArray, size_t nelems){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nelems; i++){
        Symbol *curr = symbArray + i* sizeof(Symbol); 
        printSymbol(curr); 
    }
}
```

In this statement

```
Symbol *curr = symbArray + i* sizeof(Symbol);
```

there is used invalid pointer arithmetic.

Rewrite it simply like

```
void printAllSymbols(Symbol *symbArray, size_t nelems){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nelems; i++){
        Symbol *curr = symbArray + i; 
        printSymbol(curr); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fran C It does not work for you because I am sure there are other errors in your code. Nevertheless you should correct your code as I showed.